# Error in the connection to MySql database from Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: mysql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The problem is: I connect my local database in visual studio and works, the connection works, and in the server Explorer window appears the connection with a green check that indicate is all okay, indeed the table appears and all seems right.

When I close visual studio and reopen it, the connection is broken and appears in the server Explorer window a red X.

how can I fix this error?

Comment: can you not right click and choose connect?

Comment: I successfully add a connection to my database and it appears in the server Explorer window with green tick, which means that's all okay (indeed I can see all the tables). Whenever I close visual studio and then reopen it, the db appears with a red cross on and I am not able to see the tables anymore

Comment: What options do you see on the context menu

Comment: refresh, delete, edit connection, MySQL dataexport, launch MySQL workbench, open MySQL utilities console, rename, proporty.

Comment: Have you tried refresh?

Comment: I tried it just now and says there's a problem with the password.